# Can I display SSRS detail group as a separate report?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, subreport

SSRS newby here. I am creating a management report so the specs are out of my hands.

For part of the overall project, they need a summary report that shows 4 detail regions broken up by a Quadrant group (think calendar quarters).

I am using an existing stored procedure to pull data for this summary report. The specs are such that following this summary report, they want each of the Quadrants broken out and displayed on separate pages.

Is there a way to pull the existing data from the summary report and push it onto new pages? I know I could pull the SQL data again for each Quadrant but the existing procedure is returning a combined dataset of all Quadrants. Can I use the report or the already populated dataset to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, I think you should only need one dataset (query) to support this report. The dataset should include the detail necessary for the Quadrant detail pages.

The summary section of the report should aggregate the data for all Quadrants (if that is the purpose of the summary), then for the detail you can add a single detail section inside a List data region. The list data region should have a grouping on Quadrant and then you should put whatever other data regions you want to show for each quadrant *inside* the List. This should repeat the detail section for each quadrant. You can specify page break after each group in the Quadrant grouping to force each detail section onto a new page.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I will explore that a bit. Yes, I agree I should be able to use the same dataset. Unfortunately, the summary is just as I described - the entire report, detail and all. They're wanting the detail sections repeated again on a new report page. We will have to add an additional blank column to the individual quadrant pages where managers can enter comments...

Comment: You haven't said what the layout of the report is like, but assuming the summary section is one large table (for example) then your report would consist of that summary table, followed by a list region, with a grouping set on the quadrants, and inside the list is a similar table to the summary one. Hope that helps!